# Как отфильтровать список по количеству букв в слове

Tags: python, list

У меня есть класс Product:

```
class Product():

    def __init__(self, id, category, name, srok_godnosti, volume, ves, price):

        self.id = int(id) #уникальный идентификатор
        self.category = str(category) #категория
        self.name = str(name) #имя
        self.godnost = int(srok_godnosti) #сколько дней может выдержать не портясь
        self.volume = int(volume) #объём в миллилитрах
        self.ves = int(ves) #вес в граммах
        self.price = int(price) #цена
```

и есть продукты:

```
milk = Product(124356, "Products", "Milk", 7, 1500, False, 67)

sugar = Product(309475, "Products", "Sugar", 365, False, 750, 72)

chips = Product(263849, "Products", "Chips", 128, False, 150, 103)

butter = Product(786582, "Products", "Butter", 31, False, 450, 327)

lemon = Product(283444, "Products", "Lemon", 36, False, 40, 17)

print(f"Имя : {milk.name}, ID : {milk.id}, категория: {milk.category}, в нормальных условиях может выдержать не портясь : {milk.godnost} дней, объём : {milk.volume} милилитов, вес : {milk.ves} грамм, цена : {milk.price} рублей.")
print(" ")
print(f"Имя : {sugar.name}, ID : {sugar.id}, категория: {sugar.category}, в нормальных условиях может выдержать не портясь : {sugar.godnost} дней, объём : {sugar.volume} милилитов, вес : {sugar.ves} грамм, цена : {sugar.price} рублей.")
print(" ")
print(f"Имя : {chips.name}, ID : {chips.id}, категория: {chips.category}, в нормальных условиях может выдержать не портясь : {chips.godnost} дней, объём : {chips.volume} милилитов, вес : {chips.ves} грамм, цена : {chips.price} рублей.")
print(" ")
print(f"Имя : {butter.name}, ID : {butter.id}, категория: {butter.category}, в нормальных условиях может выдержать не портясь : {butter.godnost} дней, объём : {butter.volume} милилитов, вес : {butter.ves} грамм, цена : {butter.price} рублей.")
print(" ")
print(f"Имя : {lemon.name}, ID : {lemon.id}, категория: {lemon.category}, в нормальных условиях может выдержать не портясь : {lemon.godnost} дней, объём : {lemon.volume} милилитов, вес : {lemon.ves} грамм, цена : {lemon.price} рублей.")
```

Мне нужно отфильтровать список по длине названия товара (где длина названия больше пяти) и вывести названия продуктов получившегося  списка на экран.
То есть из 5 продуктов должны вывести на экран имена продуктов где букв больше 5, а остальное убрать.
При выводе должно получиться:

> ```
> Список продуктов : Sugar, Chips, butter, lemon.
> ```

А milk исчезнет из списка, т. к. в milk 4 буквы.

Помогите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: что вы пробовали сделать? что не получилось?

Comment: prod = [milk.name, sugar.name, chips.name, butter.name, lemon.name]

prod_pro = []

for y, p in enumerate(prod):
    prod_pro.append(Product(y, 'Продукты', p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4]))
   
spisok = []
bes_spisok = []
for x in prod_pro:
    if len(x.name) > 5:
        spisok.append([x.id, x.category, x.name, x.godnost, x.volume, x.ves, x.price])
    else:
        bes_spisok.append([x.id, x.category, x.name, x.godnost, x.volume, x.ves, x.price])

Comment: print('Продукты до 5')
for i in bes_spisok:
    print(f'ID: {i[0]}\n Category: {i[1]}\n Name: {i[2]}\n Godnost {i[3]}\n Volume: {i[4]}\n Ves: {i[5]}\n Price: {i[6]}\n')
    
print("Предметы после 5")
for i in spisok:
    print(f'ID: {i[0]}\n Category: {i[1]}\n Name: {i[2]}\n Godnost {i[3]}\n Volume: {i[4]}\n Ves: {i[5]}\n Price: {i[6]}\n')


     Выводится ошибка: string index out of range/ по поводу строки:  prod_pro.append(Product(y, 'Продукты', p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4]))

Comment: file:///C:/Users/Polina/Desktop/%D0%94%D0%B7%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%201%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%202%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0.lnk

Comment: редактируйте свой вопрос. не надо простыни в комменты постить.

Comment: print(*(f"Имя : {x.name}" for x in spisok_produktov if len(x.name) > 4), sep='\n')

Comment: spisok_produktov = [sugar, chips, butter, lemon]
print(*(f"Имя: {x.name}  вес:{x.ves} грамм цена: {x.price} рублей." for x in spisok_produktov if len(x.name) > 4), sep='\n')

Comment: Спасибо большое, все получилось!

Answer (score 0):

Список продуктов изначально:

```
 spisok_produktov = [sugar, chips, butter, lemon, milk]
```

Нужно дописать:

```
 print(*(f"Имя: {x.name}, вес:{x.ves} грамм, цена: {x.price} рублей." for x in spisok_produktov if len(x.name) > 5), sep='\n')
```

x - переменная в списке. len - длинна.
len(x.name) > 5 - длина имени переменной x больше 5.

Вывод такой:

```
 Имя: Butter, вес: 450 грамм, цена: 327 рублей.
```

т.к. в butter 6 букв.

Если вместо > сделать >= (больше или равно), то вывод будет таким:

```
Имя: Sugar, вес: 750 грамм, цена: 72 рублей.
Имя: Chips, вес: 150 грамм, цена: 103 рублей.
Имя: Butter, вес: 450 грамм, цена: 327 рублей.
Имя: Lemon, вес: 40 грамм, цена: 17 рублей.
```

Слово milk удаляется, ведь в нем 4 буквы

Спасибо Сергею Ш!